# React Hooks - How to get parameter value from query string

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can I use react hooks and get  query string value?

with react class I use :
`const id = this.props.match.params.id;`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
```

in component:

```
const { id } = useParams();
```

https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params

Comment: this is terribly wrong , it will never return url query params !

Comment: yep, but his question was about param of react router

Comment: @JimmyObonyoAbor, wonder what is your solution? thanks

Comment: @smile for query params use  combination of `URLSearchParams()` and `useLocation()` react hook , like `const queryP =new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search)`  see specs for [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

Comment: Thanks @JimmyObonyoAbor, much better answer, your previous one was little negative :)

Comment: @MiroslavPapírník but the question states "query string", doesn't it?

Answer (score 27):

here is another pure javascript way

assuming your URL = localhost:3000/example?id=123

```
  React.useEffect(() => {

    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search) // id=123
    let id = params.get('id') // 123 

}, [])
```

you can also check if the query params exist or not by `has` like

```
params.has('id') // true
params.has('name') // false
```

Answer (score 12):

In **React Hooks**:

Suppose your URL is like this: `http://localhost:3000/user?name=John&id=10`

Then you can use `useLocation` hook to get your job done.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function VerifySignup() {
    const search = useLocation().search;
    const name = new URLSearchParams(search).get('name');
    const id = new URLSearchParams(search).get('id');
    console.log({ name, id })
    return (
        <div>
            Verify Signup
        </div>
    )
}

export default VerifySignup
```

Comment: So basically, `useLocation().search` is equivalent to `window.location.search`, right ?!

Comment: Shouldn't that be the correct answer?

Answer (score 5):

You can create your own hook

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router";

export default function useQueryParams() {
    const search = useLocation().search;
    const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(search);
    const params = Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries());
    return params
}
```

and then use it in you code like this

```
import useQueryParams from 'useQueryParams.js'

const { param1, param2 } = useQueryParams()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [useParams](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/useparams) and set the id as a dependency of the effect:

```
const Component = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  useEffect(() => 'do something when id changes', [id]);
};
```